# Regex to match string until first occurrence of decimal point followed by a tab

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex to achieve the following: From a list I just want all strings that have a tab after the first occurrence of a decimal point. These strings can only be at the beginning of each line. With my current regex `/^(\S+\.)/gm` I even get the string that does have 2 or more decimal points.

Here's some example code (spaces are tabs in reality):

```
aaa.            86400
ns1.dns.nic.aaa.    172800  IN  A   156.154.144.2
ns1.dns.nic.aaa.    172800  IN  AAAA    2610:a1:1071:0:0:0:0:2
abarth.         86400   IN  RRSIG   NSEC 8 1 86400 20180728050000 20180715040000 41656 . 
a0.nic.abarth.      172800  IN  A   65.22.24.17
a0.nic.abarth.      172800  IN  AAAA    2a01:8840:1a:0:0:0:0:17
ai.
ns2.offshore.ai.    172800  IN  A   108.166.113.245
whois.ai.       172800  IN  A   209.59.119.1
xn--node.ns.anycast.pch.net.    172800  IN  A   204.61.216.88
d.nic.xn--mxtq1m.   172800  IN  AAAA    2001:c50:ffff:1:0:0:0:185
d.nic.
xn--ngbc5azd.       172800  IN  NS  a.nic.xn--ngbc5azd.
```

What I need from that is `aaa.`, `abarth.`, `ai.` and `xn--ngbc5azd.` but not `a0.nic.abarth.` or `whois.ai` or any other string with more than 1 decimal point.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course there are no tabs in your sample text. But if there were, `(?m)^[^\s.]*\.(?=\t)` or you may use some other junk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^[^.\r\n]+\.(?=\t)~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XrrS4H/1). **NOTE**: you do not need `\r\n` and `m` modifier if you pass the lines as separate strings).

**Details**

- `^` - start of line (as the `m` modifier makes `^` match start of line positions)
- `[^.\r\n]+` - 1+ chars other than `.`, LF and CR
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=\t)` - there must be a tab right after `.`.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/w7uCXi):

```
if (preg_match_all('~^[^.\r\n]+\.(?=\t)~m', $str, $m)) {
    print_r($m[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaa.
    [1] => abarth.
    [2] => ai.
    [3] => xn--ngbc5azd.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can also use:

```
preg_match_all( '/^([^.]+\.)\t/m', $x, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER );
print_r( $m[1] );
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaa.
    [1] => abarth.
    [2] => ai.
    [3] => xn--ngbc5azd.
)
```

---

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zTE8XI/1)
[Ideone](https://ideone.com/8zJH8D)